# Mac accessibility API - get chrome tab

Tags: macos, accessibility, accessibility-api

I want to use the macOS accessibility API to click a button on a website in a google chrome tab.

I'm using the [Atomac](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom) package to do this.

```
chrome = atomac.getAppRefByBundleId('com.google.Chrome')
window = chrome.windows()[0]
```

But can I now get the buttons available inside the chrome window and then click on them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using selenium for accessing contents within Chrome.